# C - Pointer to Array of Strings

Tags: c, arraylist, struct

I've been stuck on this for a while now!

I have to use this given struct:

```
typedef struct ArList
{
    char **array; // pointer to array of strings
    int size; // number of elements
    int capacity = 10; // length of array
} ArList;
```

to create a dynamically allocated `Arlist` by using a function(This is where I'm supposed to come in:

```
ArList *createArList(int length)
```

Instructions given: First goal is to create an `ArList`:

```
ArList* list = malloc(sizeof(ArList));
```

Then I have to initialize the internal array:

```
list->size = 0; //Given as initially 0
list->array[list->size];
```

Lastly, (this comes later but I wanted to tested now) I have to copy a string into an element of the array.

```
strcpy(ArList[0], "CAT");
```

At this point I ran the code to see how it was going and it outputs the word "CAT" but immidiately crashes afterwards.

I'm just starting to learn about structures and memory allocation, and it all seems confusing right about now.

This is for C programming.

Comment: Is that your real code?  What do you expect `list->array[list->size]` to do?

Comment: I was trying to mimic array[N]. In case N is changed later on? Not sure if it's valid. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot allocate with `list->array[list->size]`, use:

```
list->array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*list->size);
```

and then when you want to fill the array:

```
list->array[0] = strdup("CAT");
```

if i correctly understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Think you mean `strcpy`?

Comment: No, i mean `strdup`, because list->array[0] still needs to be allocated.

Comment: That gives me a compile error: "Too many arguments to function 'strdup'

Later on I'll need to be able to insert a copy of a string into the next unused cell of the array.